# ASP.NET Core: different configuration for different instances of one app on one host

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application (.NET Core 2.1). I publish using Visual Studio (VS2019 -> *RMB on project* -> *Publish*). Server runs on a Windows Server 2019 Standard, there's an IIS installed.

Currently there are three application instances on the server. One staging instance and two production instances. For configuration I use `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable which is set in every publish profile using `<EnivronmentName>` (so I have two profiles with `<EnivronmentName>Production</EnivronmentName>` and one with `<EnivronmentName>Staging</EnivronmentName>`).

I need those environment variables to manage email sending: I need it to work for two production instances but not for the staging instance.

Now let me get closer to the problem. I need to modify those emails (just a little bit) depending on the instance: let's say for production instance *A* I need email subject to be *Instance A*, for production instance *B* I need it to be *Instance B*.

It seemed logical to me that this should be configured via publish profiles because publish profile is what makes one instance different from another. So I tried to find a way to pass publish profile name or additional environment variable to Startup.cs but didn't succeed.

It would be perfect if publishing process stayed untouched but any help/solution is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you manage to get two different values for the same environment variable on the same machine?

Comment: You need to have different configuration files for each instance and have instance specific values in them and read them in code and use them

Comment: @Crowcoder As i mentioned it earlier, I set enviromnent name in each publish profile. As I understand, it affects site configuration in IIS Manager

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya But how do I resolve configuration file depending on instance? If I could do that I simply wouldn't need new config files - I would just use instance specific info in my code.

Comment: @wunderwaffle publish must be doing something, I'm finding references to it changing web.config. Anyway, when your publish needs exceed what VS can do it might be time to move to a proper DevOps system like Octopus or Azure DevOps, Jenkins, etc.

Comment: @Crowcoder In IIS Manager Configuration Section I've found *environment variables* list, where ```ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT``` value is displayed. I wonder if I could add another environment variable there that could be set in publish profile and read from the code.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of searching and coding I finally did it. Thanks to @Crowcoder for guiding me in the right direction.

**Warning**: solution below works for publishing to IIS! I don't know if it works for any other publishing ways.

So publish profiles do change `web.config` files. And files store some of the site's settings in IIS. Therefore I needed to somehow change `web.config` during publishing depending on specified profile.

That's where [web.config transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-3.1#prevent-webconfig-transformation) come into play. One of the ways to apply transformations to `web.config` is based on used publish profile.

Those are my steps:

1. In web app directory (next to `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs`) I added web config file and named it according to existing publish profile. So imagine you have publish profile named `ProfileA`. Then you need to name your web config file `web.ProfileA.config`. **Naming is important**
2. I entered following sample there

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <location>
        <system.webServer>
            <aspNetCore>
                <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                    <environmentVariable name="ENTER_NAME"
                                         value="ENTER_VALUE"
                                         xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
                                         xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"/>
                </environmentVariables>
            </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>    
</configuration>
```

3. Then I published the app using VS as I always do.

As I understand, it searches through `web.config` in your site directory on host trying to find section `<environmentVariables>` and adds it if it doesn't exist. Then inside that section it tries to find environment variable by its name (`ENTER_NAME` in my example) and adds it there with specified value (`ENTER_VALUE` in my example).

After publishing I went to IIS manager, chose published instance and saw that my variable had been added to the list of environment variables in site configuration. It means that now I can access it through `IConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

A little known feature is that you can actually set the Environment via code before your WebHost starts up. In a .NET Core 3+ project, it would look a bit like this :

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseEnvironment("Production");
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Note that for projects below .NET Core 3, the UseEnvironment call still exists, but the WebHost builder is slightly changed so you might need to play around to work out where it sits.

For example :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseEnvironment("Development")
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Because you're setting the environment via Code, you can do things as simple as load a file in the root of your project called "environment.txt" that contains your environment and just use that.

A little more info on this feature here : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/05/03/environments-asp-net-core/